# How to sum corresponding values with same month and names of two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

The formula should sum up the column C based on Column A and B when two column value matches and displays the sum value only in the first cell D2 of Column D as shown in figure "60" & "67".

[image]

I am trying with SUMIFS but not getting the Output as required.

=SUMIFS(C2:C6;A2:A6;"A:A";B2:B6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell D2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A2&$B$2:$B2=$A2&$B2))=1,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6=$A2&$B2),$C$2:$C$6),"")
```

It should give expected output.

It might also be better/more efficient if you create a helper column (which stores concatenation results, instead of doing the concatenation multiple times in each formula).

Comment: Thank you!! it works perfect and I created a helper column as suggested.